# Animação para android

Tags: android

Como fazer esse tipo de animação do círculo para android?
[image: CM SECURITY]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um gif animado com essa animação já pronta e carregá-la num ImageView como qualquer outra imagem. Você pode usar a library do Glide pra isso. Exemplo:

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load(R.drawable.gifanimation2)
        .asGif()
        .into(image_view);
```

Não esqueça de adicionar a dependência do Glide no build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

Quando o processamento terminar, você troca o gif animado por uma imagem estática no callback de retorno.